# Order objects in a JavaScript collection

Tags: javascript, arrays, asp.net-mvc, coffeescript, underscore.js

Friends,

I have the following problem. I have a collection of objects being returned from an ASP.NET MVC controller as JSON. In the view, I want to order these objects in a specific order based on a name property.

I attempted to do so by creating a separate JS array. Based on the names property, I insert the object into a specific index in the array.

I'm sure there is a better way to solve this problem. Also I currently getting only the last condition for "events" inserted in every index position. Below is my code to date.

Thanks much!

```
<script id="tmpl-refinement-results" type="text/template">
    <% var sortedFacets = [] %>
    <%_.each(SearchAggregationDetails, function(aggValue, y){

        if(aggValue.FilterText = "News"){
          sortedFacets[0] = aggValue;
        }

        if(aggValue.FilterText = "Articles"){
          sortedFacets[1] = aggValue;
         }

        if(aggValue.FilterText = "Case Studies"){
          sortedFacets[2] = aggValue;
        }

        if(aggValue.FilterText = "Nice Exhibit Case Studies"){
           sortedFacets[3] = aggValue;
         }

    if(aggValue.FilterText = "Events"){
        sortedFacets[4] = aggValue;
    }

}) %>

<% _.each(sortedFacets, function(aggregation, i) { %>
<li>
    <a href="<%=aggregation.TypeUrl %>"><%=aggregation.FilterText %> <span class="refinement-results-list num-val"> <%=aggregation.DocCount %></span></a>
</li>
<% }); %>
```

Comment: You can sort your array by a certain property in the object

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how your JSON exaclty looks like. But `_.pluck()` from UnderscoreJS should work for you.

See the demo below and here at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/zv7bubab/).

```js
var obj = {
    post1 : {
        category: "News"
    },
    post2 : {
        category: "Articles"
    },
    post3 : {
        category: "Case Studies" 
    },
    post4: {
        category: "Nice Exhibit Case Studies"
    },
    post5: {
        category: "Events"
    }
};

console.log(_.pluck(obj, 'category'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.1/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a separate object to define the order and [`_.sortBy`](http://underscorejs.org/#sortBy) for something like this. For example:

```
// Map the strings to something that is easy to sort.
var theRightOrder = {
    'News': 0, 
    'Articles': 1, 
    'Case Studies': 2, 
    'Nice Exhibit Case Studies': 3, 
    'Events': 4
};

var sorted = _(SearchAggregationDetails).sortBy(function(o) {
    return theRightOrder[o.FilterText];
});
```

I'm assuming that `SearchAggregationDetails` is an array of Objects.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/x5q153gp/